# Compiling C++, organising include files

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to modify and compile uvccapture on the Raspberry Pi. I got the source [from here](http://staticwave.ca/source/uvccapture/) (it's just a few files).

(I think) the only external files it needs are those of `jpeglib` which I downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg/files/libjpeg/6b/).

When compiling, where do I put the jpeglib source files? UVCCapture has the following line:

```
#include <jpeglib.h>
```

**Does that mean I should put the jpeglib source files in the same directory as the UVCCapture source files? That seems messy. How can I set up the compiler (modify the Makefile?), and where should I put the jpeglib files so that I don't need to change the uvccapture include file lines?**

And a side question, how come it only includes the .h file and not the .c file? (I'm pretty new to C/C++)

Here is the Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CPP=g++
APP_BINARY=uvccapture
VERSION = 0.4
PREFIX=/usr/local/bin

WARNINGS = -Wall

CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -O2 -DLINUX -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" $(WARNINGS)
CPPFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

OBJECTS= uvccapture.o v4l2uvc.o

all:    uvccapture

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up directory."
    rm -f *.a *.o $(APP_BINARY) core *~ log errlog

install:
    install $(APP_BINARY) $(PREFIX)

# Applications:
uvccapture: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC)   $(OBJECTS) $(XPM_LIB) $(MATH_LIB) -ljpeg -o $(APP_BINARY)
```

Thanks

Comment: as a heads up your 1st link isn't there (the link for where you got uvccapture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source file (`uvccapture.c`) doesn't care where the header file (`jpeglib.h`) is -- at least it shouldn't. The compiler must be told where to look for header files; traditionally, the header files go in some directory like `inc_files/`, and the compiler is invoked with a command like

```
gcc -blah -blah -blah -Iinc_files  -c -o uvccapture.o uvccapture.c
```

If you use Make, then Make should execute a command like that. So either edit the makefile, or put the header files in the current directory.

The sane way to use `#include` in C/C++ is to have source files and header files include header files. That is, in `foo.c` there will be a couple of lines like:

```
#include <bar>
#include "baz.h"
```

and in `baz.h` there might be a few lines like:

```
#include <vector>
#include "qux.h"
```

You almost never see `#include foo.c`, because it's almost never a good idea.